# How can I get NiFi to take a multi value that is in a database single column to populate Solr index which is an array?

Tags: json, solr, apache-nifi, jolt

Been writing this question for hours...

I'm thinking that I may need to use the Jolt Transformer processor for this.

Example A single entry in a database column called "A" contains this value in a varchar field.
`"Alabama","Ohio","Texas","Missouri"`

Again the above value is 1 entry in the column "A".

The data needs to populate a Solr Index field called `"STATES"`.

Currently I have an *ExecuteSQLRecord* pulling the database data with a *JsonRecordSetWriter* for the *Record Writer*. This processor connects to my PutSolrContentStream.

The problem seems to be that the data always gets wrapped from column A in quotes " and all" already in the field get escaped.

How can I override this in order to manually set the quotes to be used?

With the way things are working right now the data sent to Solr looks like the following from the query call.

```json
[
 {
  "STATES": "\"Alabama\",\"Ohio\",\"Texas\",\"Missouri\""
 }
]
```

or other attempts to see what I can get it to output are like

```json
"STATES": "Alabama,Ohio,Texas,Missouri"
```

```json
"STATES": "'Alabama','Ohio','Texas','Missouri'"
```

What I need is for the output to be
call.

```json
[
 {
  "STATES": ["Alabama","Ohio","Texas","Missouri"]
 }
]
```

**Would the Jolt Transformer be the solution**

Examples I've seen with the Jolt have been simple where a specific value gets changed such as `STATES` becomes `"MY_STATES"`. But I'm at a loss at the moment for how to convert the

```json
"STATES": "Alabama,Ohio,Texas,Missouri"
```

to

```json
"STATES": ["Alabama","Ohio","Texas","Missouri"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can use a ***split*** function within a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "STATES": "=split(',',@(1,&))"  // & stands for the current level attribute
    }
  }
]
```

for the input

```json
{
  "STATES": "Alabama,Ohio,Texas,Missouri"
}
```

You can test by putting the `Specification` and `Input` into their boxes after toggling the **ADVANCED** tab illustrated in the following image :

[image]

Comment: But I need for the values to be: "STATES": ["Alabama","Ohio","Texas","Missouri"]

Comment: Let me try it out. It looks like what you have would work.

Comment: @edjm it will convert to what you want, eg.  `"STATES": ["Alabama","Ohio","Texas","Missouri"]`

Comment: Is it the JoltTransformJSON or JoltTransformRecord processor I need to use? And would I put the above [{...}]  into the 'Jolt Specification' Value column? Sorry. New to this Jolt thing.

Comment: Yes, put whole content to the `JoltTransformJSON` processor's spec @edjm You can also preview(test) through use of advanced tab's specification and input boxes.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work but the output even under the Advance tab is still the same original value.  I have 'Chain' specified as the Jolt Transformation DSL, and have checked a dozen times that I put in exactly what I'm seeing above. Specification is Valid according to the advanced tab also. I'm looking up documentation on this transformation stuff now. https://docs.digibee.com/documentation/components/tools/transformer-jolt/transformer-getting-to-know-jolt

Comment: @edjm I've added the image in which the result returns with no issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had put into my JSON input [ {...} ] instead of {...}

Comment: sorry another question. With the Advance tab I have to use {...} but when running the flow my data from the ExecuteSQLRecord processor gives me the data as [ {...} ]. When it is in the  [ ] then the parsing fails. I cannot find a way to get the Jolt to work when the data contains the [ ]. What am I missing/overlooking here? It seems like it would be overkill if I were to evaluate the DB results in order to get rid of the [] only to manually put them back in before the call to solr.

Comment: @edjm you can add an extra transformation to the current spec such as `{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }` eg. the new transformation will be `[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "STATES": "=split(',',@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]`

Comment: question. The formatting works using the JoltTransformJSON but it only works if I have 1 object. If there are more than one {} within the [ ] then it does not transform the values at all. What am I missing?

Comment: @edjm You might need this : `[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=split(',',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  }
]` as much as I can reproduce

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on sites to read that will be good for learning all of these things that you seem to know?

Comment: @edjm There are some sources which I like ;
[1](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), 
[2](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt), 
[3](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350), 
[4](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html).